# Manipulating Cookie using PHP cURL

Tags: http, cookies, curl, header

**What I'm trying to do:** 
I have a script that automatically logs a user in using cURL. The way the website that the user is being logged into works is that if the login attempt is more frequently than say 5 minutes, it throws an error.

However, I have discovered that that website is assigning some cookie vars to decide when to throw that error. I want to know if I can manipulate this cookie var to trick the website so that it doesnt throw the error?

**My current working code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$login_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: ".$random_ip, "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: ".$random_ip));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agents[$user_agents[0]]);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data%5BUser%5D%5Busername%5D=".$login_r['log_username']."&data%5BUser%5D%5Bpassword%5D=".$login_r['log_password'].""
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The above code works...as long as I don't run my script less than 5 minutes apart. I would like to run it every minute. I have a cronjob setup for this and I record the outcome of the login in the DB.

When the login succeeds, the headers look like this:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 09:33:39 GMT  Server: Apache
>   P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"  Expires: Mon,
>   26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT  Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 09:33:39 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate  Cache-Control:
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache  Set-Cookie:
>   CAKEPHP=deleted; expires=Fri, 23-Nov-2012 09:33:38 GMT;  path=/
>   Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=1kgh668rhu0sg0dgtj125v31b7; expires=Wed,
>   18-Dec-2013 09:33:39 GMT;  path=/; domain=.*******************; secure
>   Location: https://**********************  Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Length: 0  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 HTTP/1.1 200
>   OK  Date: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 09:33:40 GMT  Server: Apache P3P: CP="NOI
>   ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"  Cache-Control: max-age=0,
>   no-cache P ragma: no-cache X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.2.24.1-2581  Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 14582  Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8

NOTE: The "Location" line is where the "login success" redirection URL is defined by that website.

When the login fails, the headers look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 23 Nov 2013 09:36:21 GMT 
Server: Apache P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM" 
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=deleted; expires=Fri, 23-Nov-2012 09:36:21 GMT; 
path=/ Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=8ur5cc9nk145g7up50bk1fpbk4; 
expires=Wed, 18-Dec-2013 09:36:22 GMT; 
path=/; domain=.***************; 
secure X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.2.24.1-2581 
Vary: Accept-Encoding Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache 
Content-Length: 7120 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: on sucess login it will be a 302 Redirection to the home age with logged-in session but what do you want exactly?

Comment: you can not bruteforce the website with tricking the cookie the website use hte IP

Comment: @K3rnrl31 I want to reset the cookie that is created on successful login every time the login fails.

Comment: whene you assign the cookie on successfull login tou have not to login anymore just assing it and request the url will redirect you as logged-in (IF THE COOKIE HAS NOT BEEN DELETED FROM THE SERVER DB)

Comment: what you mean by "reset" ?